# Unity + ReSharper "Field can be made readonly" warning for SerializeField

Tags: unity-game-engine, resharper

ReSharper gives a warning `Field can be made readonly` when using private fields marked with the `SerializeField` attribute, e.g.:

```
[SerializeField] private Sprite _sprite = null;
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, install the [Unity Support ReSharper extension](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity).

Also, confirm that it's installed if you recently re-installed or updated ReSharper.